# Use Vuetify v-btn with loader inside a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am trying to figure out how to have my dynamically generated buttons inside a for loop each have a separate loader. Vuetify has buttons with Loaders.

The problem I am having is, When these buttons are in a for loop and one is clicked they all show the loading indicator. I would like only the one that is clicked to show the loading indicator.

HTML:

```
<div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key='i'>

<v-btn 
dark 
color="pink"
:loading="loading"
@click="loader = 'loading'"
>
  <v-icon>location_on</v-icon> Lookup
  <span slot="loader">locating...</span>
  <span slot="loader" class="custom-loader">
      <v-icon dark>cached</v-icon>
  </span>
</v-btn>

</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
data () {
      return {
        loader: null,
        loading: false
      }
    },
```

Let's say I have 3 items. The code above will generate three buttons but they all will share the same loading param. How can I have each button use its only loading param? As always any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: there a typo here `v-for="(item, i) in items :key='i'"` which should be `v-for="(item, i) in items" :key='i'`

Comment: fixed the typo, thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using the same data property for all buttons, so these buttons share the same `loading` state which affects the at one time, to make difference try to add a data property called `index` which represents the current clicked button index :

```
data () {
      return {
        index:-1,
        loader: null,
        loading: false
      }
    },
```

and bind loading prop to the condition `loading && i==index` and update the current index on click event  `@click="loader = 'loading';index=i"`  :

```
<div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key='i'>

<v-btn 
dark 
color="pink"
:loading="loading && i==index"
@click="loader = 'loading';index=i"
>
  <v-icon>location_on</v-icon> Lookup
  <span slot="loader">locating...</span>
  <span slot="loader" class="custom-loader">
      <v-icon dark>cached</v-icon>
  </span>
</v-btn>

</div>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Would you mind explaining why it worked?

Comment: I think I get it. :) Just waiting for the system to allow me to accept your answer

Comment: i edited my answer to explain more i hope that could help you

Comment: I have a new similar issue with a combo box, I have made a separate question here if you wouldn't mind taking a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57628594/how-to-use-vueitfy-combo-box-in-a-v-for-loop

Comment: But if you click a second button, this will change the index and remove the first button from the loading state, even if it's still loading...

Answer (score 2):

Its actually a lot easier than you think:

```
<div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key='i'>
<v-btn 
dark 
color="pink"
:loading="loading[i]"
@click="loading[i] = true"
>
  <v-icon>location_on</v-icon> Lookup
  <span slot="loader">locating...</span>
  <span slot="loader" class="custom-loader">
      <v-icon dark>cached</v-icon>
  </span>
</v-btn>

</div>
```

```
data () {
      return {
        loading: {},
      }
    },
```

In the beginning `loading[index]` will be undefined, so it will be evaluated as false, once you establish its value in the click event it will be evaluated as true, it worked for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use reactive array to prevent changing the index like this.

```
<div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key='i'>
<v-btn @click.prevent="testload(i)" :loading="loading[i]"></v-btn>
</div>

data () {
  return {
    loading: [],
  }
},
methods: {
    testload: function (index) {
        // reactive array
        this.$set(this.loading, index, true);
        console.log(index)
        console.log(this.loading[index])
        // stop loading after x miliseconds
        setTimeout(() => (this.$set(this.loading, index, false)), 3000)
    },
```

dont forget to input false according the length of items, this is the example:

```
getDataAll: function () {
                var i = 0
                for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    this.loading.push(false);
                }
             }
```