# How to use Vueitfy combo box in a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a v-for loop. Inside the loop is a combo box. I have 3 items in the loop so I have 3 combo boxes. When I type words into one combo box it displays those words in the other combo boxes.

I know this has something to do with the model and index but I have hit a wall and need some help.

Here is the code

HTML:

```
<div v-for="(item,i) in clues" :key="i">

<v-combobox multiple
  v-model="select" 
  append-icon
  small-chips
  deletable-chips
  @keyup="comboActive"
  @paste="updateTags(item)"
  @change="updateTags(item)">
</v-combobox>

</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
data() {
    return {
        select: []
    }
}
```

QUERY:

```
let cluesRef = db.collection('clues')
    cluesRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        var c = []
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            this.clue = doc.data()
            this.clue.id = doc.id

            c.push(this.clue)
        })
        this.clues = c

        if(this.clue.locationimagetext)
            this.select = this.splitJoin(this.clue.locationimagetext)
```

The `comboActive` method is used to set a class on the input select so when the user is typing I can style the combo box in a way that the user knows something is happening i.e. red border.

The `@change="updateTags(item)"` and `@paste="updateTags(item)"` updates the database as the user adds items to the combo box.

NOTE: saving works fine. its just during the typing that all combo boxes get the same value.

All help is much appreciated

Comment: `v-model="select[item]"` where select is a list?

Comment: @ChrisLi This partially worked. Yes now when I type in words the other combo boxes do not use the same words but I get errors when calling the updateTags method now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign key to each `select` model

```
<div v-for="(item,i) in clues" :key="i">
  <v-combobox multiple
    v-model="select[i]" 
    append-icon
    small-chips
    deletable-chips
    @keyup="comboActive"
    @paste="updateTags(item)"
    @change="updateTags(item)">
  </v-combobox>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, this is working to a degree. I am now getting issues when pulling the words back from the database

Comment: this issue I now have is on page load pulling the items from the database. Normally I said `this.select = this.splitJoin(this.clue.locationimagetext)` but this fails now because its looking for this.select. I am not sure how to handle this

Comment: Remember that all index in `this.select` when you get back from db needs to be the same as this.clues indexes. Maybe you need another way to relation both values

Comment: I am at a loss. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you get the data from the database? Can you put an example of the query->result?

Comment: Thank you Manuel, I got it! will post the solution in a sec

Comment: I supposed that you saw the scope problem in your query. You're welcome!

Comment: Let me know if this is wrong but here is how I solved it. ```if(this.clue.locationimagetext) {
                    for(var i=0; i<this.clues.length; i++) {
                        this.select[i] = this.splitJoin(this.clues[i].locationimagetext)
                    }
                }```

Comment: That's the way, nice. Note: You can use forEach instead of var i=0... but works too

Comment: I do have one more question. I need to pass the event through @change but when I do @change="updateTags(item, i, $event)" I get the array. I am trying to get the element so I can remove the class I set when the user started typing.

Comment: I can turn this into another question if you like

Comment: No problem, when you get an array, on event triggered, or in vue render page?

Comment: Manuel I went ahead and made it a separate question. here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629835/pass-the-target-element-through-change-in-vuetify-combo-box

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this bind all 3 comboboxes to the same data property `select`? I think you need different data values for each of the selects.

Comment: That is correct but this is in a loop. For this example I said 3 but it could be 300. I am not sure how to handle the data property dynamically

Comment: Have you tried setting the `v-model="select[i]"`. That should give you an array of arrays where the index matches the loop.