# Pass the target element through @change in Vuetify combo box

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I need to pass the target event through the `updateTags` method. Here is the combo box below:

When I call the `comboActive` method I can get the target event.

`KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "y", code: "KeyY", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}`

Notice, the `comboActive` method in the combo box does not send any params but in the method `comboActive(event)` I can get the target event.

I would like to be able to get the target event inside the `updateTags` method. As you can see I have tried using `$event` but this does not work

HTML:

```
<v-combobox multiple
  v-model="select[i]"
  append-icon
  small-chips
  deletable-chips
  @keyup="comboActive"
  @paste="updateTags(item,i)"
  @change="updateTags(item,i,$event)">
</v-combobox>
```

SCRIPT:

```js
comboActive(event) {
  console.log('active ', event)
  event.target.parentElement.classList.add('saving')
},
updateTags(item, i, e) {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      console.log('complete ', item, e)
    })
  })
},
```

When I add `$event` the `@change="updateTags(item,i,$event)"` I get back the array of items. I need to combo box itself so I can remove a class that was added during the `comboActive` method.

Comment: You need to create a new combobox with the results? Sorry, i don't understand the question

Comment: @ManuelRodriguezGil I am updating the question with more info :)

Comment: Ok man, now i understand, you only need to use `e.target`

Comment: i have tried the same issue [here](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/gOYgBzq?editors=1011) and it output only the selected items, if you want to play with CSS try class binding instead of accessing elements in that way

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I would love to do this with class binding but I couldn't figure it out. My goal is when the user is typing a word the combo box's border turns red. After the new items have been saved the red border disappears.

Comment: check this [pen](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/gOYgBzq?editors=1011) if it fits to your need i'll post an answer to explain that

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim almost, however, I relooked at the class approach and solved the issue using this CSS class `.v-input--is-focused .v-select__selections` it is not as elegant as I wanted but it certainly gets the job done. Go ahead and post and answer so I can accept it. Thank you for the Class tip. sometimes we can't see the trees through the forest :)

Comment: @ManuelRodriguezGil Thank you for all your help as well. I wish I could accept two answers. I really appreciate it. I am going to accept Boussadjra's answer once he posts it due to the issue got resolved via CSS classes

Comment: No problem, i made a mistake thinking on simple html components. I forgot that v-combobox $event returns itself. You can use another `array` with related indexes and `v-class` to toggle `true || false` when you fire this events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to use [`class binding`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) to handle this issue, or work with `color` computed property and change it conditionally by adding a data property called `saving` and update it in `@change` handler like :

```
   <v-combobox
             :color="color"
         ...
         @change="saving=true"
        ></v-combobox>
```

script

```
 data () {
      return {
        
        saving:false,
        select: ['Vuetify', 'Programming'],
        items: [
          'Programming',
          'Design',
          'Vue',
          'Vuetify',
        ],
      }
    },
  computed:{
    color(){
      return !this.saving? 'red':'grey'
    }
  },
```

[full example](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/gOYgBzq?editors=1011)

Answer (score 2):

Use `e.target` to get input changed.

```
comboActive(event) {
        console.log('active ', event)
        event.target.parentElement.classList.add('saving')
    },

updateTags(item, i, e) {
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.$nextTick(() => {
                    console.log('complete ', item, e);
                    console.log(e.target);
                    e.target.parentElement.classList.remove('saving');
                });
            });
        },
```

This only works on simple components. Mi mistake.

Another way you can try is setting an `Array` with same `index` and when you trigger comboActive(item, i) and updateTags(item, i) toggle this Array to `true || false`

```
comboActive(i, event) {
    console.log('active ', event)
    this.isActive[i] = true;
},

updateTags(item, i) {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.isActive[i] = false;
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: Unfortunately that comes back undefined

Comment: Manual, here is what `e` spits out: `(2) ["jason", "hi", __ob__: Observer]` in this example I typed jason and hi into the combo box.

Comment: I don't know why you cannot access to $event. I'm trying in fiddle and no trouble.

Comment: The combo box is inside a loop. not sure if that helps or not

Comment: I forgot the part of combobox, i'm sorry, wait a minute

Comment: Thank you @Manuel